# How to zip folders

Tags: files-and-directories, compression, file-transfer

I know that one can archive data with Mathematica using: `CreateArchive[source,path]`

I have a lot of folders (folder1, folder2,folder2 etc.) that I would like to compress as a batch. The result should be: folder1.zip, folder2.zip, folder3.zip.

Anyone knows how to do that with mMathematica ?

could be a starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44644428/batch-file-to-zip-folders-with-original-names

Comment: I feel this is one of those times where you should be using a dedicated program, instead of trying to do it in *Mathematica*.

Comment: @J.M.iscomputer-less I know, but it would be so convenient. I don't care if it takes a bit longer.

Comment: I think if you wish to add to an already compress zip folder it would require unzipping it, and re-zipping it with the new contents.

Comment: @user6014 Or simply putting everything into a folder and zipping it, and then deleting the original files

Comment: @james Can you describe in more detail exactly what you are after? I think one of the main reasons you haven't gotten a ton of replies here is that it's entirely unclear what you want.

Comment: @user6014 I updated my quesition

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be achieved with `Map` (`/@`).

1) Identify the folders you want to compress:

```
In[30]:= FileNames["folder*"]

Out[30]= {"folder1", "folder2", "folder3"}
```

2) `Map` CreateArchive across them:

```
In[31]:= CreateArchive /@ FileNames["folder*"]

Out[31]= {"/Users/user/Desktop/folder1.zip", \
"/Users/user/Desktop/folder2.zip", \
"/Users/user/Desktop/folder3.zip"}
```

**Edit:**

To delete the uncompressed folders after, you can run

```
DeleteDirectory[#, DeleteContents -> True]& /@ {"folder1", "folder2", "folder3"}
```

(Using `FileNames["folder*"]` here will possibly delete the .zip folders a well, so I'd refernce the original files directly)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This is exactly what I was looking for ! Is it also possible to delete the uncompressed folders afterwards ?

Comment: @james added that

Comment: I did that a lot recently, but every now and then, I had some temporary files left over. Mathematica creates a temporary folder and sometimes just leaves it there. Has someone else seen this? Adding a `Pause[0.25]` helped a bit, but not always.

Comment: To avoid the temporary folders, try the option  `CreateIntermediateDirectories  -> False` with the `CreateArchive` command.